# Python: How can I move files without changing import statements?

Tags: python

I've been writing some code which makes use of the 'import' statement to include code from other parts of the project and during the course of development I've had the need to restructure some of the code to other locations in the project tree.

The problem I've encountered when doing this is those import statements breaking. The desired behavior is that the imports don't break when I move a file. I've had experiences when developing in C# and Java where this behavior is automatic and would like a solution for Python development.

Are there any methods/tools/practices that I can utilize to keep `import x` from breaking when I move files like what I did in Java/C#? Is it possible to copy a file to somewhere else in the project tree and keep it working with no changes to the file itself?

Comment: I guess this is not that pythonic, but having to put everything into one folder like so many other python research project is doing doesn't seem to be that good of a design style. I hope that there's a lightweight solution, the best an IDE that do every configuration for us.

Comment: Why the downvote? I know that this is a very stupid question, but this is a chain of things that I really wanted to know to bring SE practices to python. I was forced to put every script into one single folder to prevent dependency problems (and this seems to be the method so many researchers decided to follow, stacking with "message passing" using files instead of proper IPCs), which as someone from industry feeling extremely bad, and adding up with other problems are causing lots of technical debts. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this issue? I am also currently trying to organize/refactor/rebuild a collection of python files and I want to do it in a way where, after completing the process, future refactoring will not result in the need to update all imports. Placing all files in a flat structure cannot be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can imagine this working is if instead of relying on relative file imports you rely on package imports. I can't recommend this unless the code you've written makes sense to be a separate package. This would work just the same as using any third party modules.

The process would look like, create a new project with the code you're hoping to import. Follow along with the [Python Setup Script](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html) documentation for your version of Python and after you've created the package you can pip install it or copy it to the modules directory of the Python environment your original project is using.

I would also add that Python's own setuptools documentation isn't amazing and I personally have used other sources such as the source code for the [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/setup.py) package, and personal experimentation to learn how to write a setup.py and setup.cfg file that will do what I want.

Comment: I agree with you on relative file imports are pretty bad, especially when you do cross-project references. Also since both of the things is rapidly changing I'm not sure whether packaging it as a module is good in such developing environment.

Comment: @xxbidiao I'm really glad you're reaching out for some software engineering advice. Especially since it seems like you're using the code for some academic/research means and there's an abundance of low quality research code, which ... makes researchers reluctant to share their code. If it's true you're doing a research project I would recommend that you open source your code as it's probably required to replicate your research anyways and it can help people provide more concrete suggestions.

Comment: Yes I agree with you on the open source part, but due to some institutional reasons, I can't do it now. Aside from that exact project, my personal python project makes me feel bad too since I and the academic people surrounding me don't know the quality-of-life practice in python software engineering and most tools needed to do proper SE in enterprise-level frameworks seems to be missing.

Comment: There's no canonical IDE for Python maybe, whereas C# has Visual Studio, and both of those products are created by the same company, and using each other. For Python it is up to you to find your own tools and your own way of working with source code, but you should still apply SE practices to your code, it's just less automatic. For instance the "problem" you are having now might be solved by choosing to communicate information between the two relevant parts of code in a different way.

Comment: @xxbidiao Oh I wish I had enough rating to comment on your question... I think you should read the documentation on python.org about 'import'. Imports are relative and there's a pattern of including an __init__.py file in each directory that you want to be able to import files from. I'll try to update my answer later today to include some information about that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Yeah there is a huge bunch of ways to do it non-automatically, but I really wanted to see, like a canonical IDE, that manage things automatically so that I don't need to spend weeks for everyone joining the group teaching them research-unrelated things and still allow them to commit high-quality code, whereas Visual Studio provides intuitive interfaces for all this benefit; Or it is at least a method that only "leave bad things to me" that after careful configuration whatsoever code submitted by others (edit: following project code style) don't break the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm supports move refactorings (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-refactorings.html), it simplifies a lot this kind of work.

Comment: why the downvote? This was not intended to be a promotion of a commercial product (there is also a community edition which is free, and which supports refactorings), but as a potentially practical suggestion to solve the OP problem.